# How to run unicorn when reboot automatically, I got Could not find gems errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, cron, unicorn

I setup my `rbenv` in `.zshrc` and on Ubuntu 12.04

and get the following errors

`Could not find tzinfo-0.3.40 in any of the sources
Run`bundle install`to install missing gems.`

Here's the command in the crontab

```
/bin/sh -l -c 'source ~/.zshrc && cd /home/poc/projects/zeus/ && bundle exec unicorn -c /home/poc/projects/zeus/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D -p 8080'
```

When I typed which ruby, I expected it returned me `/home/poc/.rbenv/shims/ruby` But `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

```
/bin/sh -l -c 'source ~/.zshrc; echo `which ruby`'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry, using the `@reboot` nickname date

You certainly want `/bin/zsh`, not `/bin/sh`, in your crontab since you want to use `zsh`

But it would be simpler to write your `sh` script for it. Read for instance the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

You might want to set your `PATH` (perhaps even at the start of that script) to suite your specific needs.

Comment: I'm so sorry.Can you explain more detail? because I couln't understant it

Comment: I added a link which should help you. You need to take several hours to learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

To fix my problem, I have to enable the rbenv environment at first,

You should change the following command to fit in your environment

I put the following line in crontab,

At first You should do

```
export PATH=/home/poc/.rbenv/shims:/home/poc/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH; eval "$(rbenv init -)";
```